# AngularJS not working on homemade chrome extension

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I've been developing a chrome extension and am using AngularJS. I am using angular to create a list that updates every time a user puts in new information and clicks the link.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Ladybug">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var application = angular.module('Ladybug', []);
  function URLController($scope){
    $scope.newSite=""
    $scope.sites=['www.facebook.com'];
    $scope.addSite=function(){
         $scope.sites.push($scope.newSite);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"</script>
<div ng-controller="URLController">
  Enter A URL : <input type="text" ng-model="newSite">
  <button ng-click="addSite()">Add</button>
  <hr/>
List of Blacklisted Sites :
<ul><li ng-repeat="site in sites">{{site}}</li></ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code online on http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_default the code works perfectly fine but when I upload the code to the chrome extension developer and run the extension it does not display the list or update. The extension loads just fine and the buttons work it just doesn't update. Does anyone know why it works online but not uploaded? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: that is a ridiculously old version of angular. it should work but won't have a lot of more current features in it

Comment: Inline/embedded code doesn't run in extension pages. Instead of guessing what's wrong you can use the built-in debugger and actually see what's happening. Each component of an extension has its own window and a debugger. You can find how to invoke it by googling.